# PHP Alphabet Loop Repeat

Tags: php

I have just started to learn PHP at work and have been asked to output the Alphabet in UPPERCASE and then in lowercase. This needs to be repeated 10 times on a page.

This is the code that i have put together however there must be and easier way to repeat this rather then just copy and pasting it 10 times.

```
<?php
for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
$Letter = chr($i);
print $Letter .", ";
}
for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
$Letter = chr($i);
print $Letter .", ";
}
?>
```

I was told by a frind that For loops are best to use rather then foreach loops.

Comment: You already used two `for` loops, why not third around both of them?

Comment: echo `abcdefge .....`

Comment: Do some timings comparing `foreach(range('A','Z') as $letter) ( print $letter . ', '; }` or even `print implode(', ',range('A','Z'));` against your for loop; and then tell your friend he's wrong

Comment: for lowercase, you can use `range('a','z')`

Comment: Thank you Mark i will give this a go and will remember to mention this to my mate! He will prob try telling me im wrong as he does this for a living lol

Comment: It might surprise your mate that some of us do this for a living as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
for ($a = 1; $a <= 10; $a++)
{
    for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
    $Letter = chr($i);
    print $Letter .", ";
    }
    for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
    $Letter = chr($i);
    print $Letter .", ";
    }
}
?>
```

Or even better:

```
<?php
for ($a = 1; $a <= 10; $a++)
{
    echo implode(', ', range('A','Z'));
    echo implode(', ', range('a','z'));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print substr(str_repeat(implode(", ", array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'))).", ", 10), 0, -2);
```

This is the shortest way I can imagine.

But what you can do is simply put a for loop around your code:

```
for ($repeat_times = 10; $repeat_times; $repeat_times--)
    for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
    }
    for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using both `for` and `foreach` cicles:

```
<?php
$prints = 10;
$alphas = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));

for ($i = 1; $i <= $prints; $i++) {
  echo "$i\n";
  foreach ($alphas as $letter) {
    echo "{$letter} ";
  }

  echo "\n\n";
}
```

Just play with the `echo` instructions to change the output.

Comment: Note that `range('A', 'Z') + range('a','z');` will work too. PHP supports the `+` operator to concat arrays. however +1

Comment: @hek2mgl `[1] + [2] == [1]` try it out yourself.

Comment: @bwoebi Sorry don't understand

Comment: @hek2mgl `var_dump(array(1) + array(2));` =>
`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
}`

Comment: @bwoebi Uuups! I didn't expected this! Thanks!!! will investigate

Comment: `range('A','Z') + range('a','z')` !== `array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'));` The difference is the keys, when matching keys are overridden (or not) and when new keys are allocated

Comment: Thanks mark and bwoebi!! I didn't know this!! (and gave the comment in the hope it is useful)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: using an additional loop at the top, solves the problem:

<?php
for ($count=0; $count<10; $count++) {
    for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
    }
    for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

or you can also do the same by:

```
<?php
for ($a = 1; $a <= 10; $a++) {
    echo implode(', ', range('A','Z'));
    echo " | ".implode(', ', range('a','z'));
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php
    for ($j= 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
        }
        for ($i=97; $i<=122; $i++) {
        $Letter = chr($i);
        print $Letter .", ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use array of characters. String is already an array.

```
<?php
$letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

$repeat = 0;

while($repeat < 10)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($letters); $i++){
        echo strtoupper($letters[$i]). "<br>";
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($letters); $i++){
        echo $letters[$i]. "<br>";
    }

    $repeat++;
}
```